# How to estimate the time of Fibonacci recursive algorithm for nth element?

Tags: java, algorithm

How to estimate the time of completion of following algorithm for Nth Fibonacci element?

```
private static double fib(double nth){

        if (nth <= 2) return 1;
        else return fib(nth - 1) + fib(nth - 2);
    }
```

Comment: You mean complexity? Or actual time? The algorithm runs in `O(phi^n)` time.

Comment: I need actual time(how long would it take to calculate Nth element). How to calculate this **O(phi^n)** for example for 200th Fibonacci number?

Comment: Run it for elements 1..10 then you extrapolate using the fact that it's `O(phi^2)`. This won't be very accurate. Is this an exercise?

Comment: Yes. I have got 45th in 6452 ms; and 10th in 1ms. How to calculate time for 200th?

Comment: Why not use the [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Closed-form_expression)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **exact** time complexity of this algorithm is... `O(F(n))` where F(N) is nth Fibonacci number. Why? See the explanation below.

Let's prove it by induction. Clearly it holds for the base case (everything is a constant). Why does it hold for F(N)? Let's denote algorithm complexity function as T(N). Then `T(N) = T(N-2) + T(N-1)`, because you make 2 recursive calls - one with the argument decreased by 1, one decreased by 2. And this time complexity is exactly Fibonacci sequence.

So `F(N)` is the best estimation you can make but you can also say this is `O(2^n)` or more precisely `O(phi^n)` where `phi = (1  + sqrt(5)) / 2 ~= 1.61`. Why? Because nth Fibonacci number is almost equivalent to `phi ^ n`.

This bound makes your algorithm *non-polynomial* and very slow for numbers bigger than something around `30`. You should consider other good algorithms - there are many logarithmic algorithms known for this problem.

Comment: How can I find out the time needed to find lets say 300th fib element using my algorithm, given that 10th element is calculated in 1ms?

Comment: Given the formula above you need about 2 * 10^62 operations. Assuming that your computer can make 10^9 operations per second on one core you will need 10^45 years. The earth and sun will die until that.

Comment: @RCola you need to use `System.nanoTime()` to calculate the running time. `System.currentTimeMillis()` isn't accurate enough.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, I hope you are joking? He needs to wait 10^45 years.

Comment: I'm just saying that if the OP wants to estimate the running time by extrapolating from the time for one calculation then `nanoTime` needs to be used.

Comment: OK. Using nanoTime() I have got 9193461ns for 10th element. =>n^10=9193461 => find out **n** => put **n** to power 300 for 300th element = time in nanoseconds. Correct?

Comment: No, it's better saying c * (1.61 ^10) = 9193461. You have to find c * (1.61^30). Which is easy to find because c * (1.61^10) = c * (1.61^10)^3 = c * (9193461) ^  3